# Finding concurrent users in a sessions table created from log entries

Tags: google-bigquery

We are exploring using Bigquery to store and analyze 100s of million of log entries representing user sessions. The source raw log entries contain a "connect" log type and "disconnect" log type.

We have the option of processing the logs before they are ingested to bigquery so that we have one entry per session, containing the session start TIMESTAMP and a "duration" value, or to insert each log entry individually and calculate session times at the analysis stage. Let's imagine our table schema is of the form:

```
sessionStartTime: TIMESTAMP,
clientId: STRING,
duration: INTEGER
```

or (in the case we store two log entries per session: one connect and one disconnect):

```
time: TIMESTAMP,
type: INTEGER, //enum, 0 for connect, 1 for disconnect
clientId: STRING
```

Our problem is we cannot find a way to get concurrent users using bigquery: ideally we would be able to write a query that partitions the sessions table by timestamp "buckets" (let's say every minute) and perform a query which would give us concurrents per minute over a certain time range.

The simple way to think about concurrents with respect to log entries is that at any moment in time they are calculated using the function f(t) = x0 + connects(t) - disconnects(t), where x0 is the initial concurrent users count (at time t0), and t is the "timestamp" bucket (in minutes in this example).

Can anybody recommend a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a public dataset with sample data to play with it?

Comment: here you go: imgdge:sopub.views and imgdge:sopub.sessions. A couple of things to note: 1) We need to join the sessions table with the views table to be able to apply content specific filters (e.g. max concurrent sessions for one specific piece of content). 2) we don't have control over when the "views" data comes in and the "sessions" data comes in, that's why we can't denormalize it and can't have all the info we need directly in one table. 3) The views table might have duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the sample data! (Available at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/imgdge:sopub.sessions)

I'll take your offer to "*We have the option of processing the logs before they are ingested to bigquery so that we have one entry per session, containing the session start TIMESTAMP and a 'duration' value*". This time, I'll make the processing with BigQuery, and leave the results on a table of my own with:

```
SELECT u, start, MIN(end) end FROM (
SELECT a.f0_ u, a.time start, b.time end
FROM [imgdge:sopub.sessions] a
JOIN EACH [imgdge:sopub.sessions] b
ON a.f0_ = b.f0_
WHERE a.type = 'connect'
AND b.type='disconnect'
AND a.time < b.time
)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

That gives me 819,321 rows. Not a big number for BigQuery, but since we are going to be doing combinations of it, it might explode. We'll limit the date range for calculating the concurrent sessions to keep it sane. I'll save the results of this query to [fh-bigquery:public_dump.imgdge_sopub_sessions_startend].

Once I have all the sessions with start and end time, I can go find how many concurrent sessions are per each interesting instant. By minute you said?

All the interesting minutes happen to be:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(time)/60)*60) time
FROM [imgdge:sopub.sessions]
GROUP BY 1
```

Now let's combine this list of interesting times with all the sessions in my new table. For each minute we'll count all the sessions that started before this time, and ended after it:

```
SELECT time, COUNT(*) concurrent
FROM (
 SELECT u, start, end, 99 x
 FROM [fh-bigquery:public_dump.imgdge_sopub_sessions_startend]
 WHERE start < '2013-09-30 00:00:00'
) a
JOIN
(
 SELECT SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(time)/60)*60) time, 99 x FROM [imgdge:sopub.sessions] GROUP BY 1) b
 ON a.x = b.x
 WHERE b.time < a.end
AND b.time >= a.start
GROUP BY 1
```

Notice the `99 x`. It could be any number, I'm just using it to generate the combinatorial all the session * all the times. There are too many sessions for this kind of combinatorial game, so I'm limiting them with the `WHERE start < '2013-09-30 00:00:00'`.

And that's how you can count concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead of sessionStartTime get sessionEndTime (or just add duration+sessionStartTime)? If you could do that something like this can be made. It is not perfect but it will give you somewhat relevant data.

```
SELECT AVG(perMinute) as avgUsersMin FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(distinct clientId, 1000000) as perMinute, YEAR(sessionEndTime) as y,
    MONTH(sessionEndTime) as m, DAY(sessionEndTime) as d, HOUR(sessionEndTime) as h, MINUTE(sessionEndTime) as mn FROM [MyProject:MyTable]
    WHERE sessionEndTime BETWEEN someDate AND someOtherDate
    GROUP BY y,m,d,h,mn
);
```

Comment: We need concurrent count per minute, e.g. let's say between 10 and 11 am for every minutes how many users there were. This is so we can gauge the popularity of content at a certain point in time

Comment: While this won't give you exactly that, it will give you number of disconnects per minute in certain timeframe. There is no easy way in any SQL to check overlapping data in date ranges. I think that you should try to prepare log in pre-processing like that. It should be fairly easy to do that if you just go through log on per minute basis, create some dictionary per minute and just check how many sessions are active that minute, if done correctly this should be O(n) complexity with a bit more memory.